# Mudar opacity gradativamente com scroll

Tags: jquery, css, rolamento

Quero aplicar `opacity` no rodapé de meu site, o rodapé esta fixo no `bottom` e atras do resto do site tipo efeito parallax. Mas não consigo fazer com que fique gradativamente a opacidade, assim que rolar o scroll o `opacity` que estava em zero fique 1 assim que a barra de rolagem chegar no meu rodapé.

Essa é a div do rodapé:

`<div id="rodape" class="rodape"></div>`

Esse é o css:

```
#rodape {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
.rodape {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #00e676;
}
```

Dentro da `div` vou colocar outros elementos como endereço, mapa do Google, etc. Como a `div` esta por trás do resto do site e fixo no `bottom`, começar a aparecer quero que a opacidade seja 0 e com o scroll vai aumentando até 1 quando acabar o scroll, pois será o fim do site.

Estou usando as informações desse [codepen](https://codepen.io/michaeldoyle/pen/Bhsif) e esse js:

```
var scroll = $('#rodape');
var range = 200;

$(window).on('scroll', function () {

  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
      height = heade.outerHeight(),
      offset = height / 2,
      calc = 1 - (scrollTop - offset + range) / range;

  scroll.css({ 'opacity': calc });

  if (calc > '1') {
    scroll.css({ 'opacity': 1 });
  } else if ( calc < '0' ) {
    scroll.css({ 'opacity': 0 });
  }

});
```

Já perceberam que não manjo muito de javascript né, mas quero deixar com esse efeito, alguém sabe onde estou errando? Existe alguma forma de fazer isso funcionar, ou alguma outra solução?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

  $('.rodape').css({
    opacity: function() {
      var elementHeight = $(this).height();
      return 1 - (elementHeight - scrollTop) / elementHeight;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.encheLinguissa {
  height: 900px;
}

.rodape {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='encheLinguissa'>

</div>

<div class='rodape'>

</div>
```

> Para calcular a opacidade, subtraia o valor scrollTop da altura da div e depois divide-o pela altura da div.

Fonte:

[scrollTop()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) - Este método retorna a posição vertical da barra de rolagem para o elemento de correspondência `(div class rodape)`

**Outra Solução:**

> A condição (`>1200`) na linha `if($(document).scrollTop()>1200){` deve ter um valor compatível com a altura da pagina (neste exemplo dada por `height: 1500px;`)
>
> Quanto menor o valor da condição `(`>1200`)` a div rodape irá surgir com menos rolagem.

```js
    var div = $('.rodape');
    $(window).scroll(function(){
       if($(document).scrollTop()>1200){
          var percent = $(document).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height());
          div.css('opacity', 0 + percent);
       }else{
          div.css('opacity', 0);
       }

    });
```

```css
.encheLinguissa {
  height: 1500px;
}

.rodape {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #00e676;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='encheLinguissa'>
qqqqqqqqqqqq
</div>

<div class='rodape'>
<p>aaaaaaaaaaa</p>
<p>bbbbbbbbbbb</p>
<p>ccccccccccc</p>
</div>
```

> transition - faz com que a transição ocorra suavemente em um tempo determinado.

Comment: deu certo mas como fica no fim do site o efeito é aplicado quase na metade do scroll teria que começar a aparecer mais pra o final do scroll, tem como controlar isso?

Comment: @ClaytonFurlanetto, experimenta a outra solução na resposta editada

Comment: sim deu certo, mas assim que a imagem aparece o opacity não esta 0 já está uns 50% visivel e como o rodapé fica atras do resto do site tipo efeito parallax não dá pra perceber muito, pois ja aparece pouco transparente, estou vendo se no codigo consigo fazer ela aparecer mais transparente.

Comment: @ClaytonFurlanetto, aumenta o valor em `transition: opacity 1.5s;` para `transition: opacity 2.5s;` ou mais

Comment: Blz agora deu certo vlw muito obrigado